# Ububtu unmet Dependencies

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I am Trying to configure unreal engine on Ubuntu 18.04, And When I run `./Setup.sh`, I got the error of a package that have unmet dependencies: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil : Depends: libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-system-web4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this ?

This is what I got running `apt-cache policy`:

```
libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil: Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 5.14.0.177-0xamarin3+ubuntu1604b1 
Version table: 5.14.0.177-0xamarin3+ubuntu1604b1 500
500 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial/main amd64 Packages 
500 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: From the version numbers, it looks like you are trying to install something ancient (pre-12.04). That is likely to introduce a *version conflict*...which is exactly what it looks like you have. Something you already have installed requires different versions - that's the conflict. Use the `apt cache policy` command with those rejected packages to determine what the conflict is.

Comment: This what i get running this command:
`libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.14.0.177-0xamarin3+ubuntu1604b1
  Version table:
     5.14.0.177-0xamarin3+ubuntu1604b1 500
        500 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial/main i386 Packages
`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil libmono-system-web4.0-cil`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt install -f` to fix broken packages.

That gives this output:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I already tried, It is not working